# Probability a 10 is rolled 5 times before a 7 is rolled once, or 4,5,6,8,9 is rolled 7 times

Tags: probability, dice

I am thinking about the math of two six sided dice, using a certain strategy, I would like to know the probability of a certain loosing event defined below.

Definitions
Probability of A = rolling a 10 = 3/36 = 0.08333
Probability of B = rolling a 7 = 6/36 = 0.16666
Probability of C = rolling a 4,5,6,8,9 = 21/36 = 0.58533333

Probability of A *before* B = .333333

Probability of C *before* A = 0.875

To loose, a 10 must roll 5 times before a 7, but also if I roll a 4,5,6,8,9 seven times before a 10, OR a 4,5,6,8,9 14 times before two 10's roll, it wins (in addition to anytime a 7 is rolled as mentioned).

So what is the probability of loosing?  How many times could you expect it to happen in 1000 rolls?

This is what I think I know.  Probability of event A happening 5 times before event B = .333333$^5$ = .00412.  Probability of event C happening 7 times before event A = .875$^7$ = .393

I don't know how to combine these two events, or figure in the third scenario (event C 14 times before event A twice or event B once).

Comment: I'm not clear on the rules!  What does a 7 do?  Does it make you win instantly?  If your tally of 4,5,6,8, or 9 reaches a count of 7 before any 10 is rolled - or it reaches 14 before 2 10's have rolled - you win.

Comment: How do you, for example, roll a 10 with two six-sided dice? Do also assume that the dice are independent? The reason you are getting a down-vote is because you are not very clear in your question and it is frustrating to read.